# Getting Correlation matrix with logical, numerical (and ordinal) values resolute ERROR?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to create a correlation Matrix between numerical values and logical values (and ordinal values). 
It was suggested to use the polycor package with `polycor::hetcor(df)`.
I unfortunately get an the following error:

> Error in if (!chkcorr(corr)) stop(sQuote("corr"), " is not a correlation matrix") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Any idea what this means and how to resolve the Error?

The ordinal values don't necessarily need to be in the correlation matrix!
SO if you have any other suggestions on how to create the correlation matrix I am open to new suggestions. Just normal `cor(df)` does not work!

```
df
Name   Log1   Val1  Log2   Val2   
A      TRUE   x1    FALSE  y1
B      NA     x2    NA     y2
C      FALSE  NA    TRUE   y3
D      TRUE   x4    TRUE   NA
...
```

while x,y are numerical, Log1 & Log2 are logical TRUE/FALSE values, Name is a character.

Thanks, Antonia

Comment: Please, provide a [reproducible example][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added but I think this could be specific to my data that I am not allowed to share. I just generally don't understand the error?